# How to write Marathi/Hindi text to PDF using itext library in java?

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, devanagari

I am using itext library for creating pdfs in java. I need to write Marathi/Hindi text to the PDF.

Please refer following similar SO Question.

[itext Marathi (indian) language display issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210833/itext-marathi-indian-language-display-issue)

I also have the same issue. Since, this is an old post, is there any support in itext as of today?

The solution mentioned in the above SO post to draw marathi text as image, since I will be having multiple such marathi texts in different tables, cells etc, so it might be difficult to draw them at exact x and y locations as data will vary.

Below is my code

```
public class MarathiFont {

    public static final String FONT = "/home/Documents/Lohit-Devanagari.ttf";
    private static String RESULT = "/home/Documents/MarathiPdf.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception{

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer =
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
        document.open();

        Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FONT,BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,true);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        PdfPCell customerLblCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("जन्मतिथि ",
                font));

        table.addCell(customerLblCell);
        document.add(table);

        document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can easily do this with iText 7 and the add-on module [pdfCalligraph](http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph). Multiple caveats apply.

Comment: have you solved problem, if yes please post answer , I have iText v5.5, ty