# Flying saucer not displaying indian languages properly

Tags: css, pdf, fonts, flying-saucer, openpdf

I am using flying saucer 9.x to generate PDFs from HTML. Indian languages like Kannada, Hindi or any other languages are not being displayed properly in the PDF.

Following is a simple html to replicate the issue.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .multiLang {
                font-family: "ArialUnicodeMS", "Arial", "sans-serif", "serif";
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="multiLang">
            <h1>
                KA:ಸ್ವತಂತ್ರರಾಗಿ, <br />
                HN:प्रत्येक व्यक्ति
            </h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And below is the java code that is used to generate the pdf:

```
public byte[] generatePdf(String processedHtml) throws Exception {


    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

        renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/fonts/Arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

        renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/fonts/kannada.ttc", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/fonts/Kannada MN.ttc", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/fonts/Arial Unicode MS Regular.ttf", "ArialUnicodeMS", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true, null);
        renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/fonts/hindi.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);


        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(os, false);
        renderer.finishPDF();
        return os.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                /* ignore */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The text was expected to be printed like the following [image: below]

But instead, it seems like the characters are broken into individual graphemes.

[image]

I have tried adding all the necessary fonts like Kannada and Hindi fonts.

I have also tried playing around with font family in the css. But the issue still persists. How do I make it work?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all self-closing HTML tags.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a backend dev and the example is only for illustration purpose :)

Comment: did you try adding the asian language jar? [itextasian.jar](https://gazelle.ihe.net/nexus/content/repositories/public/com/lowagie/itextasian/)

Comment: I tried adding the dependency. Should I be configuring it in some way?

Comment: It seems like vernacular languages are not supported by the iText versions used by flying saucer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9210833/8283737